# Query on a Many to Many relationship using through in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I'm new in Django and I'm giving myself a big headhache trying to structure this query.

- I have a **BaseProfile** connected with a *OneToOne* field to **User**.
- I'm specializing the profile in **CustomerProfile** connected with a *OneToOne* field to **BaseProfile**.
- A **CustomerProfile** has a *ManyToMany* relationship with other **CustomerProfile** (so itself) **through** a **RelatedCustomer** model.
- In the **RelatedCustomer** I specify the **from_customer** and **to_customer** *Foreign Keys*.

Maybe with an image you can understand better.

[image]

**My problem**:
**Given a user.id I need to know all the other user.id of the customers that he is connected to** (so passing through **from_customer** and  **to_customer**):

So basically, first I need to dig from User to RelatedCustomer using **reverse lookup**, take all the set, and then going back to know the **user.id** of each customer in the set.

**EDIT2:**

What I've reached so far:

```
# This gives me back a customer profile given a user.id (2)
cm = CustomerProfile.objects.get(base_profile__user=2)

# M2M lookup. Given one customer returns all the RelatedCustomer relations
# that he has as a part of the 'from' M2M
cm.from_photographer.all()
```

Chaining the previous two: given a **user.id** I obtain a **queryset** of CustomerRelated relations:

```
rel = CustomerProfile.objects.get(base_profile__user=2).from_photographer.all()
```

This gives me back something like:

```
[<CustomerRelated: from TestCustomer4 to TestCustomer2 >, 
 <CustomerRelated: from TestCustomer4 to TestCustomer3 >]
```

Where in this case the user having a **user.id=2** is the **TestCustomer4**.

**My question:**

So far so good, but now having this set how can I get **all the user.id** of the **to_customer**?
That is, how do I get the **user.id** of `TestCustomer2` and `TestCustomer3`?

Comment: Please check if this worked for you.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac thanks for your answer. I've used your links and advice but I still didn't get the point. I've edited my question adding the SQL equivalent to what I need to do.

Comment: See if you can do it in raw SQL. I will try giving you solution in django ORM, but even my ORM skills aren't that good.

Comment: I just want to say thank you for the effort in your question. I might not be able to answer it, but I'll upvote it since you made the effort to make your question clear.

Comment: made an edit, take a look.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac I also made another edit :) This question/answer is changing everyday. Thank you, I've reached a mid-point of the solution. I've just delete that bunch of SQL that was maybe introducing only confusion. I reformulated the question and cleaned up here and there.

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't been able to come up with anything, primarily because I have no little time these days. If it works with SQL, stick to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as usual whenever you get the answer it always look much more easier than what you were expecting.

I guess this worked for me:

```
User.objects.filter(base_profile__customer_profile__to_customer__in=
User.objects.get(id=2).base_profile.customer_profile.from_customer.all())
```

Many thanks to @Games Brainiac

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, this is not how you query the database in django. Secondly (since you're learning), it would be good to point out that you can run `dbshell` to try out different things. And lastly, this kind of problem is described in the documentation.

I am telling you this, because as a beginner, I also felt that it was a little difficult to navigate through the whole thing. The best way to find things is just to use google, and add a *django* at the end.

I know how you feel, the documentation search *sucks*, right? Heh, I feel you, that is why you always search the way I described it. Once you get a hang of the documentation, you will feel that the documentation title page is a little more intuitive.

Okay, so now to the answer:
To access a `ManyToMany`, `OneToOne` or `ForeignKey` field, you need to use a `__` commonly known as *dunder*.

So, this is how *I* would go about doing this. Please note that there are other ways, and potentially better ways of doing this:

```
thing_I_want = RelatedCustomer.objects.get(to_customer__id=2)
```

Note, however that if you wanted to get a list of customers you would use `filter()`. Here is an example (which uses number of purchases as an example):

```
things_I_want = RelatedCustomer.objects.filter(to_customer__no_of_purchases=16)
```

Also note that the great thing about filter is that you stack one filter on top of another. You can read more about these features in the documentation link I provide below.

That will get you what you want. Now, you might have more queries regarding this, and how it all works together. Not to fear, please click [this documentation link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/) to check it out.

**EDIT**
Seems like what you want to do can be done by django, but if you want to do it using sql, then that is possible too. For example, `SomeModel.objects.raw("SQL_HERE")`. The name of the tables are usually `<app>_<model>`.

However, what you are asking can also be done in django, using the ORM. But it will be tricky.